# overwrite css items depening on className

Tags: css

I'm having problems with my CSS markup in my code.
I'm building a control and my plan is to add a standard class to it so it has a fixed layout and add any userdefined css classes behind it, to personalise the control. but during my tests I noticed a problem which I can't resolve.

when I have an element like this

```
<div class="test1 test2"></div>
```

and underlaying code in another stylesheet file.

```
.test1
{
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   background-color: red;
}
.test2
{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

then it doesn't matter if I put test1 first or test2. the div will always be yellow only because test1 is written last on the css file.
if I replace test2 with test1 in the css file itself then the div will always be red.

how can I make the background-color overwrite incase its added a second time depending on the order its written in the className itself?

I also want to take notice I don't want to force users to use the !important tag. I already know about this and yes that works fine but I need it without. Any ideas on how to resolve this issues is welcome. I'm open for alternatives

Comment: Why not just remove test2 if you want the styles from test1 to show up?

Comment: to make sure my element has certain parameters unless defined by the user.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not understanding what your asking then.

Comment: my control add an element to the page and makes sure it has a background color also removed margin and padding to fix the layout for my control predefined by me. offcourse when another user uses the control he might want to personalise it to what he wants so he could for example change the background or add some margin with his own class. in that case he adds his class to the control the control add his class behind mine. offcouse only making changes to what he defined. and keep other settings the same. thats the idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I been researching for a long time and posted here because I couldn't find a good answer. thx to the answers and responses here I was able to find an article over the problem I'm facing here [CSS howto](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

What I'm trying to do is not possible because of the order css in generated. What I wanted is my css to work between browser default and external or internal stylesheets. I will look for an alternative solution to my project.

Answer (score 1):

You can twiddle the precedence of the class's selectors like this:

```
.test2[class*=test2]
{
  ...
}
```

This should make class test2 override other classes that have only class name selectors.

---

(sorry, this part is not correct)

<strike>If you want to *lower* test1's precedence, you could do it like this:</strike>

```
[class*=test1]
{
  ...
}
```

(I haven't tested this, you might need to name it `*[class*=test1]` instead)

Comment: looks great but is it also possible to say all other classes should overwrite test1?

Comment: That's entirely a matter of precedence in CSS. If you give the class a higher precedence (typically, by making its selector longer) then it cannot be overwritten by classes of lower precedence.

Comment: I tried your solution and it works if I will force the user to use it this way.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it so `.test2` when combined with `.test1` becomes yellow

```
.test1.test2{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

a better way tough is not to work like this at all. have a read of [this article](https://medium.com/@fat/mediums-css-is-actually-pretty-fucking-good-b8e2a6c78b06) instead. It explains a technique for CSS called [BEM](https://css-tricks.com/bem-101/) (Block, Element, Modifier) which is pretty awesome. When trying to modify a existing style it will look like:

```
.test{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
.test--warning{
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

and your `div` will look like `<div class="test test--warning">`

Comment: basicly the user who is using the control won't know the underlaying class that has to be overwritten.

Comment: then either include the user defined styles after your defaults. or apply the user styles inline on the element  `<div style="background-color: yellow"/>`

Comment: looks like it will be the only possible way. was hoping not to make to many levels